# paper.js won't paint if mouse is not moving

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a strange situation with a very simple paper.js script. If I don't move mouse, the script will not draw the text, after 5 seconds. As soon as I do the move, it is being displayed. Can someone please explain to me this strange behaviour?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simplify</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://paperjs.org/assets/js/paper.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
        setTimeout(function () {
            var textItem = new PointText({
                content: 'Click and drag to draw a line.',
                point: new Point(20, 30),
                fillColor: 'black',
            });
        }, 5000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I also noticed is that paper.js examples stops running if you deactivate browser window. I'm using Chrome

Comment: Not sure how to solve your original question. But the issue you raised in the comment was just answered on [github](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/415#issuecomment-36746572). There Jürg Lehni wrote: "It's a feature to keep processing low. Read here about "keepalive": http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/#canvas-configuration "

Comment: I thought that these two "issues" are caused by the same reason. But, it seems not. In my case, keepalive attribute does not function. Thanks anyway for this option, I didn't know of it

Comment: Maybe create an issue as well then. I guess you get better help there with your problem.

Comment: I'm not checking stackoverflow regularly... It's enough to have the github issues and the mailing list to look after. Will investigage when I have time, hopefully soon!

Comment: Did you think about the meaning of setTimeout? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout Still strange that you experience it in a different way if you are moving the mouse.

Comment: @manda "To conserve battery power and cpu usage, Paper.js normally stops all animation events when the window is not focused."  http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/#canvas-configuration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding paper.view.draw(); to the end of your function?

```
setTimeout(function () {
        var textItem = new PointText({
            content: 'Click and drag to draw a line.',
            point: new Point(20, 30),
            fillColor: 'black',
        });
     view.draw();
    }, 5000);
```